A (german) puzzle I made (with translation)
I made the following puzzle and was wondering if someone finds the correct solution and the thoughts behind all parts of it. Most likely yes, but I am also interested in plausible but possibly wrong or unintended explanations.

Der Herr trägt es,
verderbend - schmerzend,
es verzaubert die Frau.
Die Stellung beachte;
gesucht ist dies:
Ein Leib, Glieder fünf.

I'll try to give nothing away, but one could say the translation to english makes it harder.
I decided to add a translation, to prevent anyone from translating it on their own and unintendedly changing it in a way it's losing hints.
Still, I expect the english translation to be more difficult to solve.

The lord carries it,
damning - painful,
it bewitches the lady.
The order note;
wanted is this:
One body, limbs five.

Much fun solving!

Hi @bobble, the puzzle has 1 solution. Maybe I formulated the initial post imprecisely. I just meant that maybe lines of the puzzle can be interpreted differently, and still lead to the right solution.

Thanks for the clarification. In case anyone complains about this puzzle not being in English - there's precedent for foreign-language puzzles :)
